# How can i merge two lists using the technique below

Tags: list, haskell, merge

I need to take two lists and combine them making pairs of 1st element of each list, then 2nd and so on...

Input: `[1,2,3] [4,5,6]`
Output: `[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]`

Comment: What is not working with your approach?

Comment: I am new to haskell and don't know how to approach this problem at all, I've tried merging these two lists in one, using 1st element from the 1st list then 2nd one form the second. I get [1,4,2,5,3,6], but then don't know how to make pairs out of that.

Comment: you can try to implement this with *explicit recursion*.

Comment: If you could please elaborate because I currently have no knowlede on this subject, writing me a program would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as "zipping". You can use a [**`zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip). Indeed, for example:

```
Prelude> zip [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]
```

You can implement your own `zip` through explicit recursion. If one of the two lists (or both) are empty, then the result is an empty list. If both lists are non-empty, then you should yield a 2-tuple of the two heads of the list, and recurse on the two tails.

So a program will look like:

```
zip' :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
zip' [] _ = …
zip' _ [] = …
zip' (x:xs) (y:ys) = …
```

with `…` the parts you need to fill in.

Comment: At my college we are using notepad++ to write our programs and then execute them in ghci, but we are first writing: main :: IO(), main = do, i <- getLine, let a = read i :: [Int], and print (a) for example

Comment: Then we write before that the actual script

Comment: @Tyler'sruler: you can just load in the file in `ghci`, and use the prompt, so test it with `zip' [1,2,3] [4,5,6]`.

Comment: I need to make it so that when i call main in ghci and then type any two lists to make  the third one

Comment: @Tyler'sruler: the only thing you need to do is then `print (zip' firstlist secondlist)`, you probably will need to specify of the type of the items to read.

Comment: My colleagues just sent me their version of the solution: combine [] [] = []
combine (x : xs) (y : ys) = [(x,y)] ++ combine xs ys

main :: IO()
main = do
  i <- getLine 
  let a = read i :: [Int]
  i <- getLine 
  let b = read i :: [Int]
  print (combine a b)
Unfortunatelly we can't have the same way of resolving the task

Comment: So if i could just refrase the part before main :: IO(),.... combine [] [] = []
combine (x : xs) (y : ys) = [(x,y)] ++ combine xs ys.... this part

Comment: @Tyler'sruler: the exercise in *this* answer is different one than the one they have given, so you need to fill in the `...`s.